# Signature in Ethereum: Are all a transaction fields signed?

Tags: transactions, signature

Assume a transaction is tx. My question is that

**Question** 1: Does a sender sign all fields in a transaction and put the signature in the transaction?, so does it send  to the network?

**Question** 2: Is there anything in a transaction not signed by the sender?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers you seek are in the [Yellow Paper](http://yellowpaper.io), Appendix F and section 4.3.

Specifically,
[image]

This means that for a normal transaction (not contract creation) the following quantities are signed:

- The nonce
- The gas price
- The gas amount
- The To address
- The value
- The transaction data

(optionally a new signature scheme involving `chainId` is also allowed as described in [EIP 155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md))

The only non-signed elements of the transaction are `v`, `r` and `s`, "Values corresponding to the signature of the transaction and used to determine the sender of the transaction" - i.e. the signature itself.

Comment: Hi @Adrian Ad - Did this answer your question? If so it would be good to mark it as answered for the benefit of others.